# How do i read txt file in Vivado (VHDL)?

Tags: text-files, vhdl, vivado

This is a simplified example of a problem I faced with reading a txt file in Vivado. In this example, I am just reading from a txt file and comparing what I read with a signal.

The code runs well in ModelSim. However, when I use Vivado (I am more comfortable using Vivado), I get an error that says "ERROR: File in_textFile.txt is not open. Cannot call endfile on it" and an arrow pointing to the beginning of the for-loop in the test bench. This is despite having "file_open(open_v_file, "in_textFile.txt", read_mode)" right before the for-loop. The code is shown below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
library std;
use std.textio.all;

entity test is
end entity test;

architecture arch of test is
    
    constant input_width : natural := 36;
    signal  expected_in_data : std_logic_vector(input_width-1 downto 0) := x"123456789";
    

    constant v_file : string := "in_textFile.txt";
    --file open_v_file : text; 
begin

    --process
     process
        file  open_v_file   : text open read_mode is v_file;
        variable in_line    : line;
        variable good       : boolean;
        variable input_data : std_logic_vector(input_width-1 downto 0);
    begin
        --file_open(open_v_file, "in_textFile.txt", read_mode);
        while not endfile(open_v_file) loop
            readline(open_v_file, in_line);
            if in_line.all'length = 0 or in_line.all(1)='#' then
                next;
            end if;

            hread(in_line, input_data, good);
            assert good report "I/O error reading input_data" severity failure;

            assert expected_in_data=input_data report "Unexpected output. Error!" severity error;
        end loop;
        file_close(open_v_file);

        wait;
    end process;


end architecture arch;
```

The content of txt file is:
123456789

I tried to move the open file to a different place of the code, to make it global. I also tried a different format for opening the file as shown in the commented code. I also made sure that the txt file was included in the design source in Vivado, according to some online sources. But with all these modifications, I still got the same error.

Comment: Provide a [mcve], you are missing in_textFile.txt, packages kecchak_types and  sha3_types. You can comment out or remove the component instantiation with the reserved word entity. Liewise you can pare down the file to a a vector or two for a minimal reproducer. There's an overload for file_open that has a Status value output one of OPEN_OK, STATUS_ERROR (already opened) , NAME_ERROR (doesn't exist or isn't found where expected) and MODE_ERROR (file operation mode). Likely you don't have the file where the simulator expects to find it.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, I found a solution that works: Copy the txt file to the xsim folder, found in the .sim folder. In Vivado simulator, directories are relative to the xsim file. There is probably a better way to do this, but this way works.

ref: https://support.xilinx.com/s/article/66843?language=en_US

Comment: This is a common behavior in any simulator. The simulator has a concept of its execution directory and will look for files there. The common solution on Linux is to use a symlink placed in the simulation directory pointing to the file.